# Last li component of ul aligning below the rest

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm having trouble getting the final LI element to align in my nav-container. I've got the other four spaced fine and there is enough space for the fifth element to display in the container but it's getting pushed down somehow. I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening. HTML and CSS below. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
<div class='top_menu_wrapper'>
    <div class='top_menu_center'>
        <ul>
            <li class='menu_link menu'>Who We Are</li>
            <li class='menu_link menu'>Family House</li>
            <li class='menu_link ypac_logo menu'> IMAGE PLACEHOLDER</li>
            <li class='menu_link menu'>Upcoming Events</li>
            <li class='menu_link menu'>Get Involved</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top_menu_wrapper{
  min-height: 65px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%
  }
.top_menu_center{
 width:65%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:100px;
 }
.top_menu_center ul{
 list-style-type:none;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 height:100px;
}
.top_menu_center li{
 display:inline-block;
 height:100px;
 width:20%;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This is in chrome btw

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `inline-block` to `inline`

```
.top_menu_center li{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:100px;
 width:20%;
 margin:10px 0;
 padding:0 0;
 text-align:center;
}
```

You'll have some spacing issues though so I've set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rileychuggins/YF7DX/

Comment: thanks. i guess the issue then is how to space them in containers. you can't specify a height and a width if they're not inline-block elements right? could you point me in the right direction on how to format that? should I wrap them in div elements?

Comment: do you need it a specific height since it's in a containing div? you could keep it inline and add `position:relative;` `top:10px` or however far you need it from the top.

Comment: or you can float them to the left as suggested above. `float:left;` `display:block;` may be you best bet.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the sum of your `li`'s width is more than 100%. Therefore the last element gets pushed out of the box. Anyway, if you change width of the `li` from 20% to 19% it starts fitting better in Chrome. You can do the research on why 5 * 20% != 100% in this instance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WP6Lb/

Comment: ok. this is making me feel like i'm not totally crazy. the 19% fits, but it is definitely strange. I thought clearing the margins and paddding would do it.

Comment: yeah, I still don't trust `inline-block` fully on all browsers so i tend to avoid it. I actually agree with @Brian Grahams answer. I would go with the `display:block; float:left;` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should just float the `li`'s and set it up so that the `ul` clears the float.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/efgdY/

As a side note, if you intend to have them pushed down (by what looks like 10-15 pixels, as in the original CSS), you can set the `padding-top` value and add `box-sizing: border-box;` of the `.top_menu_center li`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using float: left instead of display: inline

```
.top_menu_center li{
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:20%;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

See: http://fiddle.jshell.net/RQQLJ/